# Terraform file override does not overrides location

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

My Terraform project has this statement in main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "bar"
  location = "westeurope"
}
```

I added the file: override.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "foo"

  location = "northeurope"  
}
```

So I expect to deploy name=foo and location=northeurope

But:

```
terraform plan
```

Shows: name=foo **but location="westeurope"**

using:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.51.0"
    }
  }
```

**My question**

What is the reason of this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of azurerm provider are you using?

Comment: Looks like its an azurerm specific issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2503

Answer (score 0):

According to the [terraform hashicorp](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files/override), it is possible to override the file configuration with the updated ones and terraform treats the configuration file ending in `_override.tf` or `override.tf`differently.

*I created the* `azurerm_resource_group` *named* `"bar"` *initially and* *it was created successfully as shown.*

[image]

Now I added the override.tf file configuration with the "foo" named resource group as yours and it was successfully overridden with the name as well as location as follows.

***override.tf:***

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "foo"
 location = "northeurope"  
}
```

I also used the same terraform provider version as you and made sure to use `terraform init -upgrade` rather than `terraform init`.

Because this overriding is ineffective in some versions. If you previously ran any Terraform files with `terraform init` and now running the same means, it will use the previous version only.

So, `terraform init -upgrade` will upgrade to the most recent requisite version.

*Executed* `terraform init -upgrade` *and validated the configuration* *with* `terraform validate`:

[image]

*And here I executed the* `Terraform plan`, *and as you can see, it shows exactly what it does.*

`azurerm_resource_group` must be replaced with the details given.

[image]

*Executed* `terraform apply` **and the existed resource overridden with the updated name & location.*

[image]

[image]

Other alternative ways about ***"overrides":***

1. Export an environment variable with the desired value. For example, you could `export TF_VAR_name=bar` and then run terraform in that session to change the value of the bar variable with azurerm_resource_group variables as deailed in [terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables) document.
2. And also you can use a var.tf file with a default value as shown below:

```bash
variable "name" {
   type = "string"
    default = bar
}
variable "location"{
type = "string"
deault = "WestEurope"
}
```

Update it with a new value inside the modules:

```bash
module "RG" {
  source = "../module"
  name = var.name
  location = var.location
}
```

*And module source has code in the below format :*

```bash
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "foo"
  location = "NorthEurope"
}
```